# Web application logging not working after reload in TomEE 7.0.3

Tags: tomcat8, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I have installed & I'm running TomEE 7.0.3 on CentOS. Web application is deployed through `stds.xml` context with `docBase` attribute in `< TomEE >/conf/Catalina/localhost`. For this application specific logging, is placed `logging.properties` in applications's `WEB-INF/classes` and it's working and messages are being logged in file.

When above web application reloads through Tomcat Web Application Manager (TomEE), log messages are not getting written in to application specific log file.

But if i restart TomEE service, messages are being logged in file, problem arises if web application reload through Tomcat Web Application Manager.